# Unable to customize xpath

Tags: selenium, java, xpath

I want to select all the products having rating 4.5, I could do that with the help received from StackExchange. Now I want to add the products with rating 4.5 to the cart. However, I am not able to customize the XPath. I tried the below XPath:

```
//*[@class='btn__inner']
```

HTML Code:
[image]

Code:

```
package Test_package;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class rating {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.coopathome.ch/de");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mastheadMyAccountLink']/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("ss3777010@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("Soniya@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginOverlaySubmitLoginFormButton")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/ul/li[1]/a/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='subnav--item-m_0001']/li[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a")).click();
        //String a=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-item__rating']/span")).getText();
        //System.out.println(a);
        List<WebElement> b=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-item__rating']/span[contains(.,'4.5')]"));
        System.out.println(b.size());

for(WebElement a:b)
{

    System.out.println(a.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ECiurleo I need to add all the products to cart with the rating 4.5

Comment: @Sagar007 could you please help me in this case?

Comment: Ok, I think you need to clarify your question then.  Try reframing it as "I have this list of multiple items and the code xxx and I would like to select all items with 4 stars.  I have tried the below but I get y error/selects wrong thing"

Comment: You have an answer there with the xpath for the button of the products with rating 4.5

Comment: @lauda I want the xpath for add to cart button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath for the button of products with that rating should be something like:

`//div[@class='product-item'][.//span[contains(.,'4.5')]]//button[@data-add-to-basket]`

Comment: Thanks a lot.... This xpath does work, however it adds only 1 product with rating 4.5. I need to add all the products with 4.5 rating. Could you please suggest something for that.

Comment: I could add all the products to cart thanks a lot